# Tableau provide entire data extract as .csv

Tags: export-to-csv, tableau-api

I would like to provide a .csv export of the entire Tableau data extract (and not the data of a single sheet). Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. drag any measure to a sheet (use `[Number of Records]` for simplicity
2. right click on the displayed figure
3. Click "View Data"
4. Choose tab "Underlying"
5. Click "Export All"

The whole process might take quite some time depending on how much data there is to export

Answer (score 0):

The "Underlying" tab mentioned above is now labeled as "Full Data" in updated versions of Tableau.